# Are links required in cross site navigation?

Tags: term-store, content-search-web-part, cross-site-publishing

I have a site that uses the content query search web part to display catalog list items. When I connected to this catalog, it automatically added the navigation links to the top and side nav bars.

What I noticed, is that when I set the links to hidden, I was no longer able to browse to the catalog item pages and was instead redirected. Is there a way to maintain term-driven pages without having the items in the nav menus?

Comment: How are you hiding the links? Are you doing it from the term store?

Comment: On the publishing site I'm clicking the 'EDIT LINKS' and setting the links I don't want to show. I can use css or js to hide links, but is there a way to not have the navigation links appear and all and still use term driven pages?

Comment: You should be hiding the links using the term store. Navigate to the term store and go the particular term for which you are trying to hide the navigation items. Then after you have selected the term, you should be able to modify the global or left navigation visibility of the link.

Comment: I tried this, when the 'Visibility In Menus' options are unchecked in term store, the links for the catalog items are removed. For instance, if they are visible the link would be `http://site/catalogitemrurl`, but when they are not visible the link is just set to the site itself `http://site`.